# Periodic Function interval used of another non-periodic function

Tags: functions

From any non-periodic function we can manage functions which will be periodic by expanding the function with the condition f(x+T)=f(x) where ‘T’ is the length of interval for y=f(x) which we need to expand. Considering this answer the below question

If g (x) is a periodic function with period ‘1’ defined from $f(x)=e^{2x},x\in[0,1) $ then the number of solutions to the equation g(x)=[x] is (where [.] represents greatest integer function)

(A) 6

(B) 7

(C) 8

(D) none of these

I am not able to understand what the question is asking hence not able to approach ,one point I can understand that the length of interval 'T' is $[1,e^2]$ where $e^2$ is approximately equal to 7.38.

Answer (score 1):

What the question is saying is that $g(x)$ is periodic, with a period $1$, and with its values in any one period being given by $f(y)$ for $y \in [0,1)$, with $y$ being the change in value of $x$ from the start of the period (I used $y$ instead of $x$ as in the question to help avoid confusion). The question doesn't give any specific starting point for the periods, but there is some point (actually, an infinite # of them, but just choose one) $x_0$ where $g(x_0) = f(0)$, e.g., a value in $[0,1)$. Nonetheless, regardless of which $x_0$ you use, you then have for any point $x$, where $x - x_0 = n + r$ for some integer $n$ and real $0 \le r \lt 1$, that $g(x) = f(r)$.

Visually, as shown in the example graph below where $x_0 = 0.42$, $g(x)$ is a periodic, discontinuous function, with the values of $f(y)$ for $y \in [0,1)$ being used repeatedly over every section of length $1$, starting from some point and repeating both before & after that point. Also, this means the range of $g(x)$ would be the range of $f(y)$, i.e., $[1,e^2)$.

[[image: Example discontinuous periodic function <span class=]$g(x)$ meeting the question requirements">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLhNU.png)

To determine the answer, you need to consider how many solutions there are for $g(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$ over an appropriate range of $x$ values. I'm leaving it to you to do this part, but an important thing to note is that for *all* periodic functions, the range of the function is always the same from any starting point over a set of $x$ values which are one period in length (i.e., the value of $x_0$ doesn't really matter), e.g., as in the diagram above, between $1$ and $2$, you have the latter part of $f(y)$ and then the missing, initial part of $f(y).

Answer (score 0):

The are $x$s $\in [0, 1)$ where $e^{2x} = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ so there an $x \in [n,n+1)$ there $g(x) = e^{2(x-n)} = n = [x]$.  There are $7$ such $n$s.  That's all there is to it.

---

Okay, slightly more detail.

$g(x)$ is periodic.  If $x \in [0,1)$ then $g(x) = 2^{x}$.  If $x \in [n,n+1)$ then $g(x) = g(x-n) = e^{2(x-n)}$.

So if $x \in [n,n+1)$ then $[x] = n$.

When does $g(x)=e^{2(x-n)} = [x] = n$.

Well.... when $2(x-n) = 2\{x-n\} = \ln n$ or when $x-n = \frac {\ln n}2$ or $x = n+ \frac {\ln n}2$.

As $0 \le x-n < 1$ then we must have $0\le \ln n < 2$. or that $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7$.

And if so we just need to have $x= n + \frac {\ln n}2$ where $n=1,2,3.....,7$

==== tl;dr below ======

$g(x)$ is the periodic function that if $x \in [n,n+1)$ then $g(x) = e^{2(x-n)}$.

Or in other words $g(x) = e^{2\{x\}}$

So the question is when does $g(x)= e^{2\{x\}} = [x]$.

Well $[x]$ is an integer. When is $g(x)$ an integer?

so the very lowest that $g(x)$ can be is $g(n) = e^0 = 1$.

And the limit of the highest $g(x)$ can approach but not reach is $\lim_{x\to (n+1)^-} g(x) = e^{2*1} = e^2\approx 7.389$

And $e^{2x}$ is continuous so between $[n,n+1)$ the function $g(x)$ goes from $e^{2*0} =1$ through $\lim_{x\to (n+1)^-} g(x) = e^{2*1} = e^2\approx 7.389$.

So for every interval $[n,n+1)$ the function $g(x)$ will hit the integers $1$ through $7$.

So somewhere in $[1,2)$ there is an $x$ where $g(x) = e^{2\{x\}} = [x]=1$.  In fact it is $g(1) = e^{2\{1\}} = e^{2*0} = 1= [1]$.

And somewhere in $[2,3)$ there ans $x$ where $g(x) = e^{2\{x\}} = [x]=2$.  We could even go as for as solving this. $0 < \ln 2 < 2$ and so if $x = 2+\frac{\ln 2}2$ then $g(x) = e^{2\{2+\frac {\ln 2}2\}} = e^{\ln 2} = 2 = [2+\ln 2]$.

And so on.  In $[3, 4)$ we have $g(3 + \frac {\ln 3}2) = 3=[3+ \frac {\ln 3}2]$ and so on.

In $[n, n+1)$ where $\ln n < 2$ we have $g(n+\frac {\ln n}2) = e^{2*\frac {\ln n}2}= n = [n+\frac {\ln n}2)$.

And $1,....,7$ are the only integers where $\ln n < 2$.